# How Many Items Can be Found and Where Are They?

Tags: lotr-war-in-middle-earth

It is really hard to find much information on this game.  Between guessing and NPC help, I have managed to find a few items - the Palantir, a second elven blade, second Mitril Coat and a 'Glowing Vial' (Phial of Galadriel?).  The manual mentions some others (Red Arrow, Scepter of Annuminas, Dwarven Ring and Silver Orb).

Having to zoom in to the party to see any items makes guessing difficult outside of checking all the towns and ruins.  So the question is, where are all these items exactly, as well as any I might be unaware of.